# Getting downloading status from downloads running in background

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, asynchronous, express

What I am trying to do is here. My code format is below. I am calling `downloadAllImages()` function when user submits a form at `/download` and `downloadAllImages()` function puts all downloads in background(Images will be stored at server) as it will run asynchronously and sends response `Downloading images in background...` to user. I have a session variable `req.session.download_status` which I will increment on finishing of each download And user will get his download status by submitting form at `/get_download_status` which will return the value of `req.session.download_status` variable. But it is not working to get download status at threads running in background updates the `req.session.download_status` locally ((values printed on console increments) and user is only getting the initialized value which is 0 in code below. I am using `express` for creating app.

```
var request = require("request");

function downloadAllImages()
{
    ...
    ...
    ...

    req.session.download_status = 0;

    for(var i=0; i<total_images;i++)
    {
        source  = "path/to/file/which/will/be/downloaded";
        url     = "path/to/save/file";
        download(source, url, i, function(message){
            //updating the session.download_status variable in callback
            req.session.download_status++;
            console.log(req.session.download_status);
        });
    }
    return res.send("Downloading images in background...");
}

var download = function(uri, filename,i,callback){
    request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
        request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close',function(){
            console.log("image "+i+" downloaded!");
            callback("ok");
            });
        });
}
```

So what I need is a way by which the background threads can update value of some variable in app (value of a session variable in my case, which is not working), so that I can show the download progress to user by submitting form at `/get_download_status` repeatedly and stop when download is complete.
Please suggest any way by which I can get it. Thanks..

Comment: Provide the function serving /get_download_status

Comment: This is only returning the value of req.session.download_status variable.     app.post('/download_status', function(req, res){
  if(req.user)
  {
   console.log("download_status= "+req.session.download_status);
     res.send((req.session.download_status).toString());
  }
  else
  {
   res.send("");
  }